# Apache Server won't start on MAMP

Tags: apache, windows-10, mamp

When I start my servers, apache turns green, turns back off, then the MySql server starts.

I have tried changing the apache port from 80 to 8080 and 9999. I have uninstalled and reinstalled MAMP twice. I tried XAMPP but ran into an error where Tomcat 7, which comes with XAMPP, is not compatible with java versions past 9. I have tried making changes to the httpd.conf file according to some similar questions.

```
[warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```